# Pine script tradingview alert problem. Different conditions

Tags: pine-script

I have this piece of code

```
if(condition)
 crb=true
plotchar(crB,text="Long",color=color.green)
alertcondition(crB, title='Long', message='Long')
```

So, `plotchar` works as I expect - that good.
But `alertcondition` must work the same as `plotchar` because of same condition.
But it works different: when I have a plotchar -> alert doenst work and I need turn alert on through UI with different conditions.

The question is:

- Can I make alert through code? Without turning alert through UI?
- Can I make same conditions with alert and plotchar any other ways?

Error example:
[image]

Comment: So, maybe It could  happens in seconds time frame. It happens on 56 sec, but I have 1min bar. 
In theory there was long before 56sec. And I get alert. And in last 4 secs - i get dump.

Comment: 1) Alerts always get created via GUI, it can't be done programmatically. 2) it depends on the condition. For example, if you are using trigger `on_bar_close`, you might try to add to your `condition` `barstate.isconfirmed`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I make alert through code? Without turning alert through UI?

You have to enable alerts manually. I recommend you read [this](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/annotations/Alert_conditions.html) and [this](http://www.pinecoders.com/faq_and_code/#alerts) pages.

> Can I make same conditions with alert and plotchar any other ways?

You can apply same or different conditions to those two functions. But you have to manually set the alerts in any case.

Comment: I know about alerts updates and dependence on update scripts.But it is not my case.
I made i example pics: https://ibb.co/6HGPGG5

Comment: Okay, can you show us your code. Please format it into a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Exact. Would help with real code, because the one you showed doesn't make sense. You're showing `crb` in your `if` block and testing your plot and alert on `crB`. Plus, the `crb=true` in the `if` block will generate a compile error if you use the same variable to test the plotting and the alert, as it's only initialized locally in the `if` block.